# Proxied objects methods

Tags: java, proxy

Recently working with proxies objects i made my way to difficult question... i would like to share it and to have your opinions... an, perhaps, a solution... if the question proves to be valid.

Using dynamic proxy, the idea is to delegate the work to another `class` that implements the `InvocationHandler` `interface`, and overwriting the invoke method we can intercept any method invoked on the target object, granting as the possibility to add behavior and later delegating to the target object (maybe the real or other proxy) using reflection.
You have to have an `interface` that a `concrete` `class`, whose objects we like to proxify, implements. So we work with the interface.

The matter, i think, comes because with proxies object only the first invoked method is intercepted... that means : if inside the method of the `concrete` object (the object whose class is concrete, not the interface) there are calls to others instance methods, those methods will be directly invoked by the `concrete` object and not via the proxy (there before not passing thought the invocation handler again). 
I know that class of the "Dynamic Proxy" is considered a subclass of the `interface`, but **not** of the `concrete` class.. so inside the `concrete` class the "this" keyword cannot refer to a proxy object, as long the proxy object class is not a subtype of `concrete`.., in fact is a "sibling" of `concrete` because `concrete` and class of the "Dynamic Proxy" are subtypes of `interface`.

Please, have a look and the following scenario putting in code, where i found quite a problem situation.

```
public class Example
{

    static interface OutputerInterface
    {
        String getText();

        void out();

        void setText(String data);

    }

    static class Outputer implements OutputerInterface {

        private String txt;

        public Outputer()
        {
            this.txt = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getText()
        {
            return txt;
        }

        @Override
        public void setText(String data)
        {
            this.txt = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void out () {
            String text = this.getText();
            System.out.println (text);
        }
    }

    static class OutputerInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        private OutputerInterface outputer;

        public OutputerInvocationHandler(OutputerInterface concreteEntity)
        {
            this.outputer = concreteEntity;
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
        {
            String methodName = method.getName();
            System.out.println("Intercepted " + methodName);
            if (methodName.equals("getText"))
            {
                if (this.outputer.getText() == null) { // only if not setted
                    this.outputer.setText("Hi, i am outputer");
                }
            }

            return method.invoke(outputer, args);
        }
    }

    static OutputerInterface proxify (OutputerInterface entity) {
        return (OutputerInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                Outputer.class.getClassLoader(),
                Outputer.class.getInterfaces(), 
                new OutputerInvocationHandler(entity));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OutputerInterface outputer;

        outputer = proxify (new Outputer());
        String text = outputer.getText(); 
        System.out.println (text); // this works!

        outputer = proxify (new Outputer());
        outputer.out(); // this doesn´t works
    }
}
```

Is there are a way to make sure that the getText() is intercepted wherever it is called directly from the proxy or not.
Thanks!
Greetings!
Victor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of Java's built-in dynamic proxies: you can only implement a number of interfaces, but never extend a class.

In your case, what I suppose you are trying to do is extend `Outputer` and no, you cannot do that with dynamic proxies, by design. You should try a run-time code generation library such as [CGLib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: THanks martin. I see that is a limitation. I don't know a bit of CGLib (only that hibernate and spring libraries implementation use it, in order to do their magic behind the curtains)

Comment: @Victor It's not specific to dynamic proxies, though, it's just how object oriented languages work: if you wrap object A with object B, object A's `this` will always bind to A and never to B. You just need to have B *extend* A.

Comment: Yes, but the scenario that initially forces me to get to this point is more complex in order to explain here and inheritance is not posibly... so i managed to resolve the problem in other way. But is totally diferent topic my friend.

Comment: Is very curious by the way, but in other proyect, in fact, i use class inheritance and composition (with an object of the same extended class) at the same time, like a degenerated composite pattern or perhaps some kind of decorator.. anyway, others histories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the concrete class with a reference to the `InvocationHandler` that is driving it, and to use that reference in place of 'this' (uimplicit or explicit) in the appopriate places.

Or you could have the concrete class *implement* `InvocationHandler,` although it's hard to see the point ;-)

Comment: I see.. but doing that means that the concrete class knows about the fact that he is proxied by other... forcing to establish a new dependency (a ciclic one)... a last resort of solution i thing.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is really just a derived class, nothing to do with dynamic proxies at all?

Comment: Ohh sorry @EJP, i just see your comment... as i say to Martin, for my concrete problem a can't use inheritance. But i thought about that too.